# wp_enqueue_script jquery and jquery ui not working

Tags: jquery, wp-enqueue-script, datepicker

I am using the following script to call my Jquery and Jquery UI as well as a custom-script.js. Currently it works to the point of being able to see the resource in the inspector and the  tag's are outputted. However the code I use on the page like .datepicker just doesn't work. However If I use a hacked script tag and include my own jquery files my code works and .datepickers works. You can view the site at http://fiftyfity.com/place-an-order/ this is the version with the wp_enqueue_script running. I am stuck I want to use enqueue but it breaks my site.

**wp_enqueue_script**

```
function wptuts_scripts_basic() 
{
    // Register the script like this for a plugin:
    //wp_register_script( 'custom-script', plugins_url( '/js/custom-script.js', __FILE__ ) );
    // or
    // Register the script like this for a theme:
    wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-script.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-core') );

    // For either a plugin or a theme, you can then enqueue the script:
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_basic' );
```

**Ouputted Html**

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fiftyfity.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://fiftyfity.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.core.min.js?ver=1.8.16'></script>
```

**My hacked script tag** *this works If I comment out the wp_enqueue_script

```
$url = content_url();
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>/themes/fiftyfityNew/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $url; ?>/themes/fiftyfityNew/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your first block of inline datepicker js is before jQuery and jQuery UI.

When you use wp_enqueue_script your script tags will be output where your `wp_head()` action hook is located.  Move your inline datepicer js below wp_head and your jQuery should work.

[image]

You should also be using the no conflict wrapper for your inline datepicker js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("datepicker").datepicker({ });
```

Comment: still doesn't work after changing that. Don't know why.

Comment: Works for me in Safari.